# Naming convention for /var/lock/subsys on sysvinit with multiple pids

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, init.d

In this [Tips and Tricks article from Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/008jun05/departments/tips_tricks/), it is said:

> When a service is started through an init script, a file is touched in
>   the /var/lock/subsys/ directory with the same name as the init script.
>   When the service is stopped, this file is removed. The contents of
>   this file are unimportant for the scope of this article, as long as
>   the filename is the same as the init script.

However, some services might require multiple locks.  For example, [one of the GitLab init scripts](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/init/sysvinit/centos/gitlab-unicorn) requires a lock for unicorn and a lock for sidekiq:

```
# The PID and LOCK files used by unicorn and sidekiq
UPID=$APP_PATH/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
ULOCK=/var/lock/subsys/unicorn
SPID=$APP_PATH/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
SLOCK=/var/lock/subsys/sidekiq
```

Would it have been better if the developers had used `/var/lock/subsys/gitlab-unicorn` and `/var/lock/subsys/gitlab-sidekiq`? Or perhaps a directory `/var/lock/subsys/gitlab/`?

Could this problem be avoided by somehow using a single lock file?

What is the best practice for this situation?

Comment: Use EL7 with systemd, which handles multiple instances just fine without any weird tricks like this.